# How to enable system-caching of FILESTREAM data?

Tags: c#, sql-server, filestream

I have a `SQL Server 2014` database with `FILESTREAM` data (mapped to a local harddrive on the same server). When I retrieve a 10 MB file using the code below, the data retrieval (from a server on the domain) is almost constant (I get ~30% better performance the second time).

Now, MSDN states that [FILESTREAM uses the NT system cache for caching file data](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg471497.aspx).

**Shouldn't my 10 MB file be cached by my local system, making subsequent retrievals much faster? Why don't I see this effect?**

```
byte[] data = null;

// Reading FILESTREAM data requires a transaction!
using (var transaction = new TransactionScope())
{
    var fileStreamData = GetFileStreamData(guid);

    using (var stream = new SqlFileStream(fileStreamData.FilePath, fileStreamData.TransactionContext, FileAccess.Read, FileOptions.SequentialScan, 0))
    {
        data = new byte[stream.Length];
        stream.Read(data, 0, data.Length);
    }

    transaction.Complete();
}
```

Comment: Are you also running that code on the local machine where the database is? If you're across a network then the network speed will be your primary constraint. (My reading of the link is that the NT Cache etc on the db server is used, rather than that on a remote machine, as this has the benefit of freeing up other sql resources)

Comment: Am voting to migrate this, as it may get more authoritative answers on dba.stackexchange...

Comment: The machine is on the local network, but not on my local machine. The network speed is of course the primary constant, but a local cache would make subsequent calls independent of network speed.

Comment: I updated my prev comment, but my reading of it is that its not local cache used - just cache on the server, as it removes load from the main database engine.

Comment: I don't think the windows file system cache caches files from remote locations - it would have no easy way to know that the cached data wasn't stale without having to hit the network again anyway.

Comment: Why not use filetable access directly to the file on the share - think that's even cleaner.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever I'm pretty sure there must be *some* caching for file shares. Many apps use inefficient IO patterns. I doubt every ReadFile results in a network IO.